# Enable certain dates in a datepicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I am looking for a datepicker in React where I can enable only certain dates. All the other dates need to be disabled. I can pass a list of dates to the datepicker and it will only allow the dates within this list to be enabled. Does any one know a datepicker that allows this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `includeDates` from [React Datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/). Modify it with your List of dates.

```
<DatePicker
  selected={startDate}
  onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
  includeDates={[new Date('2020-08-08'), new Date('2020-08-09')]}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

One example using https://reactdatepicker.com/

```
const allowedDates = ['2020-06-04', '2020-06-05'];

return (
    <DatePicker
        filterDate={(d) => allowedDates.includes(moment(d).format('YYYY-MM-DD')) }
    />
)
```

Comment: What does the 'moment' do in the example?